# Connection to SQL Anywhere 10 *.db file

Tags: c#, sqlanywhere

How to connect to SQL Anywhere 10 db? I have tryed the instruction written here http://www.sybase.com/detail?id=1054947 but they are way out of date. And the dll that they have provided does not work under .net 4.0 no matter that they have stated it work. 
So anyone may help me here please? Thanks for all the help in advance.

UPDATE:

So when i try to use the Sql Anywhere Dll that they have provided i get this error:

Could not load file or assembly 'iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere, Version=10.0.1.34152, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f222fc4333e0d400' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

And the DLL is there. I have searched google alot and so far i have found that they have problems with this version, but i`m unable to solve the problem or find newer dll for SQL Anywhere 10. So if anyone have know a solution please give me a hint.

Comment: Please define "does not work", how exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found the solution to my problem. I just downloaded version SQL Anywhere 11 and used the DLL from this version and all Worked out.